# How to solve equations containing multiple $|x|$s?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Suppose I have an equation which looks like:

$$|x-2| + |2x+1| = 3$$

or,

$$|x-1| + |x-3| - |5x-1| = 2$$

> How should I solve such problems?

What i do is generally a kind of "hit-and-trial" method but is there an even better method to do so?

***Thanks!***

Comment: We know that $|y|=y$ when $y\geq 0$ and $|y|=-y$ when $y<0$.  Therefore, you can try all the cases, e.g., $(x-2)+(2x+1)=3$, $-(x-2)+(2x+1)=3$, $(x-2)-(2x+1)=3$, and $-(x-2)-(2x+1)=3$.  But, be sure to check your final answers, this can give you extraneous answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that always works (especially for inequalities of the same type, and also for nonlinear stuff in the $| \cdot |$ and for multiple variables) is doing case analysis, such that for each $| \cdot |$ you have 2 cases to look at.

In your first example that would be:

**Case 1**: $x-2>0$ and $2x+1>0$

**Case 2**: $x-2>0$ and $2x+1<0$

**Case 3**: $x-2<0$ and $2x+1>0$

**Case 4**: $x-2<0$ and $2x+1<0$

it is some work, but often a lot of cases are not important, because they are impossible, such as Case 2 here.

Comment: All right...So suppose we have three such $|.|$s, then I will have to solve $2^3 = 8 $ cases?

Comment: yes, but e.g. in your 2nd example, 4 of them will disappear, because they are not possible.